# Else if evaluates bool incorrectly

Tags: c#, boolean, if-statement

Here is my code:

```
if (addNewRecord == false)
        { MessageBox.Show("No action selected. \nSave cancelled."); }
else if (editCurrentRecord == false)
        { MessageBox.Show("No action selected. \nSave cancelled."); }
else{.....}
```

`addNewRecord` and `editCurrentRecord` are both bools that I have checked have a `true` value. When I do as above the messageboxes will still show as if the bools were `false`. However, if I only comment out the `ELSE IF` it will continue with the `ELSE` as intended. Am I missing something fundamental here? Thanks for any input.

EDIT: Both of the messageboxes don't show just one. I am checking the values of both bools before the IF statement with MessageBox.Show(addNewRecord.ToString());and the same for the other bool. They are working as intended. The problem only happens when I try to evaluate both of the bools, either with else if or with an OR statement.

Here is all the relevant code:

```
namespace E_Z_Rent
{
public partial class Bookings : Form
{
    bool addNewRecord = false;
    bool editCurrentRecord = false;

    public Bookings()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void bookingsBindingNavigatorSaveItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(addNewRecord.ToString());
        MessageBox.Show(editCurrentRecord.ToString());
        if (addNewRecord == false)
        { MessageBox.Show("No action selected. \nSave cancelled."); }
        else if (editCurrentRecord == false)
        { MessageBox.Show("No action selected. \nSave cancelled."); }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("OK");
        }
    }

    private void EditFieldsCheckBox_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (EditFieldsCheckBox.Checked == true)
        {
            editCurrentRecord = true;
        }
        else 
        {
            editCurrentRecord = false;
        }
    }

    private void bindingNavigatorAddNewItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        addNewRecord = true;
    }
}
}
```

I have got it working as intended by doing:

```
   if (addNewRecord == true || editCurrentRecord == true){
          MessageBox.Show("OK");
      }
      else
      {
          MessageBox.Show("No action selected. \nSave cancelled.");
      }
```

I am still puzzeled by this so if anyone else can say why this happened I will be checking back. Thanks for all the suggestions everyone.

Comment: What you are saying is impossible.

Comment: When do you execute that code, and when did you checked ?

Comment: Try refactor to if (!addNewRecord || !editCurrentRecord)) { MessageBox.show(...); } else { .... }

Comment: I don't believe that both the bools are false. Prove it with a self-contained testcase. Otherwise, look for race conditions, checking the wrong variable, etc.

Comment: Are you saying that _both_ messageboxes are showing?

Comment: When the program enters inside IF or ELSE IF blocks it will not enter ELSE block. You can rewrite IF and ELSE IF blocks into one IF.

Comment: Not impossible, I've seen it happen, unfortunately. Very unlikely however, because there were a lot of things going on that were causing it to mess up like that. (Compiling as 32-bit fixed it in that specific case)

Comment: First you check if (editCurrentRecord == false) and check if that fails

Comment: In any case, I recommend changing the messages so they are different. "(1) No action selected. \nSave cancelled." and "(2) No action selected. \nSave cancelled." will suffice, for debugging purposes.

Comment: @DanielDaranas is right and then take some time , be easy and then give it a look.

Comment: Do these bools have get accessors that change the state of anything?  Equality overridden?

Comment: Another recommendation. You say you check that the bools are true with "MessageBox.Show(addNewRecord.ToString());". This is a strange way to check that a bool is true. Try this one instead: "Debug.Assert(addNewRecord);"

Comment: It seems my guess was right alhough down votes :(

Answer (score 1):

It seems you want to do this;

```
if (addNewRecord == false || editCurrentRecord == false)
        { MessageBox.Show("No action selected. \nSave cancelled."); }
else{.....}
```

Comment: Don't you mean `||` and not `&&`?

Comment: At first I wrote || but when downwoted I advised && . As others stated I thik we are talking about a misunderstanding of a problem.

Answer (score 0):

Your algorithm is wrong.
You will go to the final else case only if both addNewRecord AND editCurrentRecord are true.
If any one is wrong, you will pop the "No action selected" message.